# How do I represent a hex value in a python string?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have some code in C that expects char buffer that looks like this:

```
 char buf[ 64 ];
    buf[0] = 0x01;
    buf[1] = 0x11;
    buf[2] = 0x61;
    buf[3] = 0x08;
    buf[4] = 0x01;
```

I am trying to create this buffer in Python, and pass the pointer to the C code. I created buf as follows,

```
buf = create_string_buffer('0x01 0x11 0x61 0x08 0x01', 64)
```

but when I pass the pointer to my C code, it looks like the C code is reading the ASCII code for 01, not a hex literal.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python hex literals are escaped by `\x`

so in your case the string to pass into your c function would be written as

```
'\x01\x11\x61\x08\x01'
```

There is a table [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in the python2 docs listing the escape sequences that python understands (corresponding [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for python3).